# Можно ли закрыть другое Android приложение из своего

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Есть ли способы реализовать это, возможно это можно на рутированных телефонах или нужно также иметь подпись служебного приложения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, если нету ROOT прав или если это не твоё приложение которое имеет такую удаленую опцию

Comment: Если у телефона разблокированные ROOT права, то возможно ?

Comment: Если есть рут права можно делать всё что душе удобно